# UIViewと同じ場所・同じサイズでAVCaptureVideoPreviewLayerを設置したい

Tags: swift, xcode

StoryBoardで置いたUIViewと同じ位置・同じサイズでAVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer（カメラからの映像)を設置したいのですが、ズレが生じます。CaptureViewが同じにしたいUIViewです。どのように修正したらぴったりあいますか？ご存知の方、ご教授お願いします。

```
// 画像を表示するレイヤーを生成.
let myVideoLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerWithSession(mySession) as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
myVideoLayer.frame = self.CaptureView.frame        
myVideoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

// Viewに追加.
self.view.layer.addSublayer(myVideoLayer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myVideoLayer.frame = self.CaptureView.bounds
```

ではありませんか？

---

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var CaptureView: UIView!
  var myVideoLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mySession = AVCaptureSession()

    self.myVideoLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerWithSession(mySession) as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    self.myVideoLayer.frame = self.CaptureView.bounds
    self.myVideoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    self.CaptureView.layer.addSublayer(self.myVideoLayer)
  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.myVideoLayer.frame = self.CaptureView.bounds
  }
}
```

Comment: (myVideo_frame , {{250, 50}, {100, 100}})
(myVideo_bounds , {{0, 0}, {100, 100}})
(CaptureView_frame , {{250, 50}, {100, 100}})
(CaptureView_bounds , {{0, 0}, {100, 100}})　という状況で、myVideoLayerのframeをCaptureViewのboundsといっしょにさせてもズレます。

Comment: 回答者さんの表現に問題ありと判断したので、文意が変わらないという条件で、修正させていただきました。

Comment: self.view.layerに追加しているようですが、self.CaptureView.layerを親にしたいのではないのでしょうか？

Comment: その通りです。self.CaptureView.layer.addSublayer(myVideoLayer)に修正しました。(myVideo_frame , {{0, 0}, {468, 468}})　(CaptureView_bounds , {{0, 0}, {468, 468}})で意図の通りですが、実際の画面を見るとmyVideoの左上で開始位置は合っているものの縦・横ともにCaptureViewよりも広くなります。

Comment: AutoLayoutが親ビューのサイズを別のタイミングで変えているのと、レイヤにオートリサイズがないからでしょう。ずれていたのはboundsと親レイヤを間違えていたからですが、サイズの変化に追従しないのは別の話です。

Comment: 私の理解が付いていけていないので大変申し訳ありませんが、具体的にどのように対処すればいいのか理解できておりません。なお、self.myVideoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFillのパラメータを変えると変化するようなのですがこちらは関係ありませんでしょうか？

Comment: 追記のコードを見逃しておりました。viewDidLayoutSubview()で問題解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: よかったじゃねーか。おめでとう！